# Result is not 0, but ORA-01476 divisor is equal to zero - SQL

Tags: zero

When I say:

```
    NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_MEN.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 1,0) +
     NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_BIM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) +
     NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_TRI.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_SEM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 3,0) +
     NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_ANU.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 5,0) as Realizadas_Tot, 

    NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_MEN.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 1,0) +
  NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_BIM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) +
 NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_TRI.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) +
 NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_SEM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 3,0) +
 NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_ANU.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 5,0) as Programadas_Tot
```

Then Programadas_Tot and Realizadas_Tot bring me some integer numbers.
But need to divide them:

```
     (
        NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_MEN.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 1,0) +
        NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_BIM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + 
    NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_TRI.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + 
    NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_SEM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 3,0) + 
    NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_ANU.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 5,0)

        )
                         /
        (
        NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_MEN.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 1,0) +
  NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_BIM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) +
 NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_TRI.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) +
 NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_SEM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 3,0) +
 NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_ANU.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 5,0)
        )     


                      as APPtot
```

But it shows me the error "ORA-01476 divisor is equal to zero".
I read a lot about decode and case, but i think it is not for what i want to do.
I tried a lot of ways with NVLs and NVL2s, but it keeps me saying that.
Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

For those who can have the same problem as I had above, here is my solution:

```
    NVL(  
           NULLIF(
                NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_MEN.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 1,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_BIM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_TRI.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_SEM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 3,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_REALIZADAS_ANU.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 5,0)
                ,0)  
                /    
           NULLIF(
                NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_MEN.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 1,0) +  
                NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_BIM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_TRI.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 2,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_SEM.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 3,0) + 
                NVL(OSS_PROGRAMADAS_ANU.NUMERO_DE_OS  * 5,0),0)
                ,0) 
                * 100 AS APP
```